# Which folder to put Caldera forms CiviCrm plugin in?

Tags: caldera-forms

I'm not an IT person so please bear with me.

Trying to install Caldera Forms CiviCRM plugin but not sure which folder to locate it in. Have put it in

/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext

via FTP for now but it hasn't come up on the extensions list. But now I'm thinking maybe it should be in a WP folder instead of a Civi one as it links the Caldera form WP plugin to CiviCRM. So I put it in the WP ext folder but still no sign of it in the WP or Civi backend.

Where do I put it? Any ideas are much appreciated.

Just a small charity so trying to wing it on a zero bugdget as much as possible!

Answer (score 3):

Caldera and Civi Caldera is a wprdpress plugin, you can locate them under wp-content/plugins/

Comment: Thanks, yes I have put the Caldera forms plug in in the WP files. It's the seperate Caldera forms CiviCRM plug in that links the two that I'm not sure where to put. Find it here https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm

Comment: both should go in plugin directory

Comment: Thanks so much, all working now. And, of course, makes sense when you think about it :)